# How to deselect all options from multiselect in Backend?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using the extension reCAPTCHA. There is a multiselect and I selected two options.

[image]

I successfully deselected them by holding CTRL while clicking on them. But if I save then they are selected again. Is this a known bug?

How can I workaround it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the related field in the the module configuration (system.xml file), then add this line:

```
<can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
```